# How to keep Webview running as a BackgroundTask C# UWP Windows 10

Tags: c#, webview, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, background-task

I am creating a WebView in my C# code and Navigate it to a URL that is streaming music, when I click myPlayButton, without displaying the WebView in my UI. And it's playing the streamed music very well. But when the app get suspended (minimized), the webview stops running.

I am trying to use this BackgroungAudioTask Sample:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundAudio

Any idea if I can make the WebView work as the Audio works in a Background Task?

Comment: There's no way to keep the WebView running in background. You need to extract the audio source and directly play it.

Comment: This might help you [Using a webView in a background task?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6a089242-91f2-4577-87fd-8d1f96758109/uwpusing-a-webview-in-a-background-task?forum=wpdevelop) or read this [Webview app running in background?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8a431df3-bae0-4082-9e64-df8887fcbc98/uwpc-webview-app-running-in-background?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: Background audio assumes you have the actual source stream to play with (MP3, AAC, etc). If you're trying to play the audio from a webpage in the background by rendering that webpage in a BackgroundTask, then you're doing it wrong and need to re-think things.

Comment: What if the audio source in question is encrypted via EME? https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/eme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MediaElement's Source can be assigned to any URI. 
I don't need any WebView, just a MediaElement that of course can be called on a Background Task.